# How do I locate a string in a PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching for a string in a pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977798/searching-for-a-string-in-a-pdf-files)

I'm working on an application that must find a location string in a PDF file. The string will look like "Location: XXXXXXXX" where XXXXXXXX is the value I need to use in my application.

How do I read this string from the PDF? Is there a library that I can use to read this? Once I get the string from the PDF I know how I'll process it. I just need to get the value out of the PDF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need something which can parse the PDF (you can't just search the file). What language do want to use?