# Search a String inside the PDF and if Match found Open PDF with the Highlighted text C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am working on a Specific task where i need to Search a string in PDF collection and Open the PDf where it found the matches (open those pages where it found the matches)

Please assist

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried? What is the question? Without the code, we cannot even deduct what your problem is. And if you want to get a full code, unfortunately Stack Overflow is **NOT** a place for that. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a library such as [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) in order to accomplish this task. Please refer to this question, Carter already posted some example code on how to do this: [Searching for a string in a pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977798/searching-for-a-string-in-a-pdf-files)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth indexing the text content of the PDF files to search on that (possibly by page) if you have a lot of files. Then open the PDF at that page.